# table header on left side in Bootstrap?

Tags: html

I haven't seen any examples while searching through google. I've tried making `thead` float on left and `tbody` on the right, but it didn't work. How to have a table header on the left side instead of showing it on the top ?

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Carter</td>
            <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Parker</td>
            <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Rambo</td>
            <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you want the headers down the left side of your table, simply write the markup differently

See [**this demo**](http://www.bootply.com/4N6s1QjOEb)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <td>Carter</td>
      <td>Parker</td>
      <td>Rambo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Email</th>
      <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
      <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
      <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But if you're trying to dynamically populate the data in the table, that makes things alot harder. Is there an easier way to do it to have the normal html structure and change it with css?

Comment: Of the top of my head, I would just use td's without any th's and then target the first td in a row with the selector tr:first-child

Comment: @Henry you could do that, but doing it this way uses the existing bootstrap styling and is more descriptive of what the purpose of the element is.

Comment: I agree, it would be easier to read if it was actually th, but who would you want it to be readable for? If the code is generated or dynamically changed from the base format, then it wouldn’t make much difference. 
If you want the first column to be th, you’d need to iterate through either the table or the data as you write it into the table.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably coming too late, but I thought I should send this. Using bootstrap's list group works fine, but you would have to tweak it. Here's an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <ul class="list-group rounded-0">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary border-right-0">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary border-right-0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary border-right-0">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary border-right-0">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary border-right-0">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="list-group rounded-0">
    <li class="list-group-item border-left-0">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-left-0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-left-0">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-left-0">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-left-0">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS: For some reason, the '.rounded-0' class name does not work here, but it works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: How can I set a specific size for both, or how can force them to have the same size? (the left column and the right one)?

Comment: Hey, @Carlos . You can easily add a size constraint through `style="width: {value}px"` to either of the `<ul>` elements.